# Bash script to benchmark two domains and plot in single graph with two different colors

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have achieved benchmarking of two domains and plotting them in single graph. All is left now is to change the color of plotted lines for respective domains.

```
plot=$plot" 'benchmark_server_data_$counter.dat' using 10 smooth sbezier with lines title '$x' lc rgb 'blue'" # This is the line where i need to replace blue with array
```

Like for example say, for domain1.org i want green color and for domain2.com i want blue. I think i need to create an array of colors and use for loop. I have tried but having lot of trouble.

```
while [ $i -lt 1 ]
do
what="http://domain1.org/,http://domain2.com/"
if [ -z "${what}" ];
then
echo "You did not specify a webserver to benchmark!"
else
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
arr=$what
counter=0
echo "set term png transparent truecolor" >> _temp.txt
#echo "set terminal png" >> _temp.txt
echo "set output 'out.png'" >> _temp.txt
echo "set title 'CodersHangout Webserver' tc rgb 'green' font 'Times-Roman, 20'" >> _temp.txt
echo "set size 1,1" >> _temp.txt
echo "set key left top tc rgb 'black' " >> _temp.txt
echo "set grid y " >> _temp.txt
echo "set xlabel 'Requests' font 'Times-Roman, 25' tc rgb 'green'" >> _temp.txt
echo "set ylabel 'Response time (ms)' font 'Times-Roman, 25' tc rgb 'green'" >> _temp.txt
echo "set xtics font 'Times-Roman, 20' tc rgb 'green'" >> _temp.txt
echo "set ytics font 'Times-Roman, 20' tc rgb 'green'" >> _temp.txt
echo "set object 1 rectangle from graph 0, graph 0 to graph 1, graph 1 behind fc rgbcolor 'gray' fs noborder" >> _temp.txt
plot="plot"
    for x in $arr
    do
            echo "> Running benchmark for $x"
            if [ "$counter" -gt 0 ];
            then
            plot=$plot","
            fi               
            plot=$plot" 'benchmark_server_data_$counter.dat' using 10 smooth sbezier with lines title '$x' lc rgb 'blue'" #Need to change the color of curve for different domains!
            ab -n $total -c $concurrent -k -g benchmark_server_data_$counter.dat -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate' $x           
            counter=$(( counter + 1 ))      

    done
IFS=$OIFS
echo $plot >> _temp.txt
gnuplot _temp.txt
rm _temp.txt
rm benchmark_server_data_*
exec /opt/lampp/htdocs/serverstat/autoftp.sh
exit
fi
i=1
done
```

Comment: Isn't it more of a bash question cause i just need to make an array and loop through that array containing color names
`plot=$plot" 'benchmark_server_data_$counter.dat' using 10 smooth sbezier with lines title '$x' lc rgb 'blue'" ` This is the line where i need to replace blue with array name.

Comment: I took you at face value : "All is left now is to change the color of plotted lines for respective domains.". Better to highlight (in the body of your question) that info. +1 for excellent first question. Sorry I don't have time right now to help , but keep posting and Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @shellter I will keep a check. You can always come back and help. I can wait. Since, no one else seems interested in this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

arr=(http://domain1.org/ http://domain2.com/)
colour=(blue green)
for ((counter=0; counter<${#arr[@]}; ++counter));{
  echo ${arr[counter]}, \'${colour[counter]}\'
}
```

Output:

```
http://domain1.org/, 'blue'
http://domain2.com/, 'green'
```

I would not recommend to redefine `IFS` as later on it can cause hard-to-detect problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying first of all. 
I have not tried it but it looks fine to me. Thought it needs lot of modifications but this gave me a good idea on how to do it. Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bhavyanshu: The pleasure is mine!